# In merge sort why not merge each sorted sublist into a rolling list?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort

So for merge sort when splitting I'd have

```
HGFEDCBA
HG FE DC BA
H G F E D C B A
```

For merging instead of

```
GH EF DC AB
EFGH  ABCD
ABCDEFGH
```

Why Not

```
H G F E D C B A
GH F E D C B A
FGH E D C B A
EFGH D C B A
DEFGH C B A
CDEFGH B A
CBDEFGH A
ABCDEFGH
```

The only thing I can think of is that merge sort is usually implemented recursively and that its easier to merge using the first way if using recursion to split.

Comment: I think what you're describing is not a merge sort, but an insertion sort.

Comment: @MarkRansom lol! oh yeah I get it now, that makes sense. The number of comparisons is less, and there'd be no point to split for merge sort if i was merging that way.

Answer (score 1):

As some of the comments have mentioned, your second picture is actually depicting insertion sort instead of merge sort. I understand your confusion, as in your example insertion sort would *run faster* than merge sort. An insertion sort of a reversed list would be O(n), as every new element added to the output array would only need to compare one element before being inserted. Merge-sort, however, requires O(n logn) comparisons in all cases.

But you are correct in saying that merge-sort has less comparisons than insertion sort in general. If the list was already sorted ("ABCDEFGH"), for example, every new element added to the output would have to compare itself to the whole output before being added to the end, which would be O(n^2) time complexity.